# How to get table column count when specifying custom bottom-row?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have the following table

```js
<b-table
    ref='table'
    :fields='fields'
    :items='provider'
    :busy.sync='isBusy'
>
    <template v-slot:bottom-row>
        <!-- TODO: Is it possible to not hardcode it? -->
        <b-td colspan='7' class='text-center'>
            <b-spinner></b-spinner>
        </b-td>
    </template>
</b-table>
```

Is it possible to somehow get the column count and use it in the `colspan` instead of hardcoded `7`? I presume I can use some convoluted logic with a custom prop to cover this but there's probably a better approach. I can also use e.g. `999999` which surprisingly works.

I've tried `colspan='fields.length'` but that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close with your try

In order for vue to understand that you want to pass a variable as the attribute value, you need to add a colon in front of it, like so:

```
 <b-td :colspan='fields.length' class='text-center'>
```

If you do it like this:

```
 <b-td colspan='fields.length' class='text-center'>
```

colspan would parse the `fields.length` as a string "fields.length", not the javascript computed value for the variable fields.length `7` for example.